# Aborting Execution, If Filename is changed

Tags: python

This was A Question Asked by my teacher. "How Would You Stop Your Script From Executing, IF Filenamed is renamed by User."

I had sumthing this idea in my mind.

```
#consider the name of the script to be myscript.py
import os
signal = 0
while 1:
    if "myscript.py" not in os.listdir("."):
        signal = 1
    else:
        if signal:
            break
        else:
            #do the requirements
```

But then He said, whatif, the user has a file named "myscript.py" already in the directory, and he changed the name of the script, the script would run well. And there I got stuck.

I am using python2.7, OS: Windows, Allowed To use Any external Libraries if required, Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, anything wrong with my name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__file__` attribute of modules contains the full pathname of the Python script that contains it.

Comment: @lgnacio thanks for response, would you mind, showing a small working example?

Comment: heh put `print __file__` into a somescript.py and run it from the command prompt...

Comment: Thanks Just Now I found the usage :)